# Sphinx autodoc works locally but not on Read The Docs

Tags: python-sphinx, setuptools, python-packaging, read-the-docs, autodoc

I have a GitHub repo ([here](https://github.com/fsantanar/rtdtest)) which is extremely basic and only meant to reproduce a problem I had with another repo (CPU Health Checks also in my public repos)

It consists on a package called rtdtest which locally is a rtdtest/ folder with an empty `__init__.py`. This file has two simple modules cpu_health.py and utilities.py where cpu_health.py imports utilities.py with the statement

```
import rtdtest.utilities as utilities
```

In this case making a package is not that necessary but in my "real" repo I need it to access modules in subfolders within the proyect's root folder

My problem is that even though I am able to produce the documentation I want locally with sphinx which includes DocString generated documentation created with `automodule` statements in index.rst, when creating the documentation in Read The Docs the build passes but with warning messages

> WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'cpu_health' from module
> 'rtdtest'; the following exception was raised: No module named
> 'rtdtest' WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'utilities' from
> module 'rtdtest'; the following exception was raised: No module named
> 'rtdtest'

Saying the modules from the package were not imported and suggesting to me that RTD is not recognizing rtdtest as a package but as a module (although I could be wrong there)

Locally the package is found with the line

```
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))
```

In file conf.py (conf.py is 2 folders ahead of the root folder of the project in docs/sphinx/)

My (minimalistic) configuration files requirements.txt, .readthedocs.yml, setup.py, docs/sphinx/conf.py, and docs/sphinx/requirements.txt are included in the GitHub repo (couldn't put specific links because stackoverflow called the message spam)

And my main documentation file is:
[index.rst](https://github.com/fsantanar/rtdtest/blob/main/docs/sphinx/index.rst)

In the admin Advance Settings section of my repo I have checked the "Install Project" box to "Install your project inside a virtualenv using setup.py install" but I haven't checked other one. For documentation type I chose "Sphinx HTML"

I tried multiple times to edit my conf.py file to add folders to the path using sys.path.insert but no combination of current and parent folders worked.

I also tried replicating the solution proposed in [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65874617/readthedocs-and-autodoc-fail-to-find-my-package-during-build) who apparently had a very similar problem and was able to solve it, but even trying to mimic their configuration files didn't work

Does anyone now what might be the problem? I am sorry in advance if this is clearly stated in the RTD documentation but this is my first time using the tool and I couldn't find a solution there

Please let me know if there is any additional information I should provide to help solving the problem

Cheers and thanks
Felipe

Comment: but I tried adding line
sys.path.insert(0, Path(os.path.abspath(__file__)).parent.parent.parent.parent.absolute())
To conf.py which should give me the directory above rtdtest/ and actually does it locally (considering that conf.py is located in rtdtest/docs/sphinx) and I got the same problem. I also tried to add different folders based on the current folder but didn't work as well. Should I be adding that folder to path in some other way?

Comment: sorry about the bold "file" word in the previous comment, it should be \_\_file\_\_

Comment: You can not have `setup.py` in the same `directory` as `__init__.py`. You use `find_packages()` in `setup.py`, and as far as I know this function will not find the import package (the directory containing the `__init__.py`), if the `setup.py` is inside the import package. -- Check this [packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) for a good and modern project directory structure. -- Usually if you have to do `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH` modifications it is a red flag that the packaging is not correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sinoroc! I simply shifted the modules and the __init__.py file into a src/ folder, updated the new package name in the modules and the .rst file and then the documentation worked with no problems :)

Comment: @FelipeSantana Having `src/__init__.py` is another red flag. If you want `rtdtest` to be the top level import package, then you shoud have `src/rtdtest/__init__.py`. I recommend you look again more carefully at the project directory structure in the [packaging turoial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: You are right @sinorc, I just modified the package structure and put the modules inside a src/rtdtest/ folder. I also added lines "packages=find_packages('src')" and "package_dir={'':'src'}" to setup.py (I am using that instead of pyproject.toml) and modified the .readthedocs.yml file to contain
python:
  version: 3.8
  install:
    - method: pip
      path: .
      extra_requirements:
        - rtdtest
Now the documentation works locally and in ReadTheDocs and I don't need the lines to modify the path in the conf.py
Do you think this is appropriate? If you do I will update my answer

Comment: Yes, this seems the correct way. This is more or less how I do it in my projects.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved thanks to @sinoroc suggestion and the project structure suggested presented in this  [packaging tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/). The structure of the project was causing problems because I had the __init__.py file in the root of the project along with setup.py.

Apparently that also produced problems for installing the package in some computers so it was extremely important to fix it.

I just created a /src/rtdtest folder within the root of the package and shifted the .py files there. Then I updated the new package name in the module's import statement and .rst files,  I also added lines "packages=find_packages('src')" and "package_dir={'':'src'}" to setup.py, and modified the .readthedocs.yml file to contain:

```py
python:
  version: 3.8
  install:
    - method: pip
      path: .
      extra_requirements:
        - rtdtest
```

Now the build in ReadTheDocs worked fine, creating documentation from the module's DocStrings as expected

Comment: Having `src/__init__.py` is another red flag. If you want `rtdtest` to be the top level import package, then you shoud have `src/rtdtest/__init__.py`. I recommend you look again more carefully at the project directory structure in the [packaging turoial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: Just edited this answer to reflect the new structure. Thanks again!